# About comparing two strings

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I'm new to programming, and I'm using java. Here's a program I wrote:

```
class HelloApp {

    static String hi;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = args.length;
        if (length > 0) {
            hi = args[0];
            sayHi();
        }
    }

    static void sayHi() {
        if (hi == "hello") {
            System.out.println("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Why doesn't inputting "java HelloApp hello" make "Hello!" appear on the next line?

Comment: Java requires .equals() method for String class equality test. == is used to compare if two classes refer to the same data.

Comment: why was this migrated to programmers? there are a billion "comparing strings in java" threads on SO ..?

Answer (score 10):

```
if (hi == "hello") {
```

should be:

```
if (hi.equals("hello")) {
```

---

`==` checks if the two references are pointing to same object in the heap, while `equals()` checks if the two String references are pointing to objects that having the same String value.

Comment: Using FindBugs, [you can automatically detect errors like these](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ)

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing strings in a wrong way...

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
static void sayHi() {
    if (hi.equals("hello")) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

this should solve your problem..

Answer (score 2):

`==` tests reference equality, not string equality. You want to use `.equals` instead:

```
if (hi.equals("hello")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `String`s incorrectly.  The proper way to check for string equality is via `str.equals(anotherStr)`, or `str.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherStr)`.  The `==` operator checks if the strings point to the same memory location, not the contents.

Answer (score 1):

as neilvillareal said you can make use of str.equals(anotherStr), or str.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherStr) methods,
Please refer following link for understanding difference between '==' & 'equals/equalsIgnoreCase'method : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221